# aws ec2 describe-instances IAM role does not work

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

My EC2 instance has a IAM role below.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "~~~~",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/myrole": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I run the "aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id i-00169bf14adaf25e4" command,

I got error "An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation."

I tested full EC2 authority IAM role, and works.

And read this https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=512129 but it was about "Resource".

Official document does not talk about IAM role. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html)

I think I missed some "Action" part, but couldn't find it.

Can somebody tell me Which IAM role is suitable for me? or how can I find it?

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: Can you please describe what you are wanting to achieve? Are you trying to grant permission to call `DescribeInstances`, but only for instances that have a tag called `myRole`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein That's correct. get permission `Describeinstances` for instances that have a tag called `myrole`.

Comment: I think your code is currently checking whether the Tag `myRole` has a **value** of `true`. (See [IAM EC2 Resource Tags](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-ec2-resource-tags/)) I'm not sure whether you can simply test for existence of a tag name, regardless of value.

Comment: I found this is not my fault.. I heard my company's role has a bug. that role, "ec2:ResourceTag/myrole": "true" is right. Thanks for answer. @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this policy and attach it to your IAM role (currently attached to your EC2 instance). This will return all instances in that account. Use the filters flag with `tag :key` option to only return instances with  desired tag key/value pair.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:DescribeInstances",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
}
```

---

> ben5556 ([Freelancer](https://www.fiverr.com/ben5556))

Comment: I don't know what's the difference with my IAM role. My role still doesn't work without "Condition" part